# DirSync a must for AD FS on Azure

Tags: azure, adfs2.0

Is DirSync a must for AD FS hosted on Azure Virtual Machines?

I keep reading Azure solution with DirSync. Is it absolutely impossible to federate directly without syncing active directory.

I am looking to implement Federated Web SSO on Azure, it would be a huge set back having to sync client Active Directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need DirSync for AD FS to function properly with Azure. What's the setback, specifically? The only real caveat I can find is a 300,000 object limit, not sure if that's per domain but it seems they're open to lifting the limit if you contact support.

If it's the setup you're concerned about, it's pretty basic. You will likely need clients to provision a VM, but that's not crazy talk or anything. Here's a few (short) TechNet articles to walk you through it:

- [Prepare for directory synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151831.aspx)
- [Active directory synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn144766.aspx)
- [Install or upgrade the Directory Sync tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151800.aspx)
- [Synchronize your directories](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151771.aspx)

Comment: Well for security reasons we just simply thought clients wouldn't approve of this

Comment: @MyName You think they will set up AD FS and a trust, but balk at the idea of installing DirSync? I don't see why it makes a difference.

Comment: it seems a bit odd for us to hold their AD user credentials when all we want to do is authenticate against the AD

Comment: I'll mark this answer shortly.. I just want to make sure it has to be done

Comment: I see your point... that's ugly. Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-identity/#ad Take a look at the Using Windows Azure Active Directory bit.